# forecasting ARIMA model with extra regressors

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

Suppose i have some time series as below and i want to forecast `c1` one step a head, doing so is pretty straight forward and easy in R:

```
testurl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jtpQaSxNY1V3b-Xfa5OJKDCLE6pNlzTbwhSHByei4EA/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv"
test = getURL(testurl)
mydata = read.csv(textConnection(test), header = TRUE)
data <- ts(mydata['c1'])
fit <- auto.arima(data)
fcast <- forecast(fit)
fcast
```

note that the numbers is just random numbers, and the auto.arima suggest us to use an `arima(0,1,0)` and the forecast one step a head is 52.

however, what if one want to use `c2` and `c3` to improve (in terms of aic and bic for example) the out of sample forecast? how would one actually continue then?

```
c1   c2     c3
40   0,012  1
41   0,015  1
42   0,025  1
40  −0,015  1
44   0,000  0
50   0,015  0
52   0,015  1
51   0,020  1
50   0,025  1
52   0,030  0
53   0,045  1
52   0,030  1
52   0,025  0
52   0,000  0
51   0,010  0
50  −0,02   1
48  −0,025  1
49  −0,030  1
51  −0,040  1
52  −0,350  0
```

Comment: You may be able to use the argument `xreg` to add the extra columns. But you will need to supply example regressors for the forecast `auto.arima(data, xreg=as.matrix(mydata[-1]))`

Comment: thanks for your comment, example regressors would be a value for, lets say, c2 one step ahead? and if so, c2 has to be forecasted or predicted as well? suppose this is maybe a better topic in the stats section..

Comment: Yes. If you supplied a value for `c2` and one for `c3`. You can add that matrix to the forecast. Remember, you are not forecasting all three columns, rather you are forecasting `c1` based on time and `c2` and `c3`. The time variable is inherently supplied, the others must be supplied by you.

Comment: thanks, i might probably lack some theory here, the values of `c2` and `c3` one step ahead is supposed to be supplied by me but isn't the best way of picking `c2` and `c3` actually to forecast them separately and pick that value?

Comment: You can do that. get a `ts(c2)` estimate and the same for `c3`. I've used that before.

Comment: When I said `supplied by you` I did not mean to pick it randomly. Usually, you would have a test set and a training set. In this case, you have to create a test set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're trying to fit a dynamic regression model to your data with `xreg` in `auto.arima()`. You can automatically determine a model fit using something like this:

```
tsdata <- ts(mydata)
fit <- auto.arima(tsdata[,1], xreg = as.matrix(mydata[,2:3]))
```

To generate your 1-step ahead forecast you will need to supply a `matrix` of future values of `C2` and `C3` to the `xreg` argument in the forecast function. One way you could do this would be like this:

```
fc.c2 <- forecast(tsdata[,2], h = 1)
fc.c3 <- forecast(tsdata[,3], h = 1)


newxreg <- as.matrix(cbind(fc.c2$mean, fc.c3$mean))

fc.c1 <- forecast(fit, xreg = newxreg)
```